# Moving from PDFBox 1.x to PDFBox 2

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have been using PDFBox 1.8 to work with pdfs. Now I'm planning to move to PDFBox 2.0-RC-2. I'm having some trouble in migrating.

With PDFBox 1.8, I used to get tokens from a PDPage using:

```
PDStream contents = page.getContents();
PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(contents.getStream());
parser.parse();
List<Object> tokens = parser.getTokens();
```

However, `page.getContents()` returns an InputStream in PDFBox 2. How do I get PDStream? Should I use `page.getContentStreams()` (which returns Iterable) and iterate through it? Also, the constructor `new PDFStreamParser(COSStream)` seems to be deprecated.

The other issue I have is with image replacement. I was replacing one image with another using `replaceWithStream`

```
PDResources resources = page.getResources();
Iterable<COSName> xObjectNames = resources.getXObjectNames();
if (null != xObjectNames) {
    for(COSName xObjectName : xObjectNames){
        PDXObject object = resources.getXObject(xObjectName);
        if (object instanceof PDImageXObject) {
            PDImageXObject img1 = (PDImageXObject) object;
            PDImageXObject img2 = ....
            img1.getCOSStream().replaceWithStream(
                    img2.getCOSStream());
        }
    }
}
```

The `replaceWithStream` method was deprecated in PDFBox 1.8, so in PDFBox 2.0, it has been removed completely. What is the other way to replace img1 with img2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to the first part of the question:

```
PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(page);
parser.parse();
List<Object> pageTokens = parser.getTokens();
```

Answer to the second part of the question:

What should work if both images have the same filters, size etc is this:

```
OutputStream os = img1.getCOSStream().createRawOutputStream();
InputStream is = img2.getCOSStream().createRawInputStream();
IOUtils.copy(is, os);
is.close();
os.close();
```

Update:
If they are not identical, also do this:

```
COSStream c1 = img1.getCOSStream();
COSStream c2 = img2.getCOSStream();
for (COSName name : c1.keySet())
{
    c1.setItem(name, null);
}
for (COSName name : c2.keySet())
{
    c1.setItem(name, c2.getItem(name));
}
```

Comment: @drunkenfist sorry about that. I'll investigate this tomorrow (it's midnight here). What type of images were the old and new images? (jpeg, pixelmap, ccitt?)

Comment: Sorry, noticed just now that the IOUtils.copy doesn't work as expected. When I try to open the pdf, I get an error saying insufficient data for an image. It was working earlier with 1.8 when I used replaceWithStream. I can see that the InputStream has contents. Do I need to somehow write the OutputStream back to the pdf? I assume not.

Comment: @drunkenfist you need to save the PDF, obviously. Which you likely did with 1.8.

Comment: Yes, I do save the pdf. Do the images have to be of the same format? The new one is definitely a jpeg, because I convert it to a jpeg manually. Not sure what the old one is. How can I check the format of the image?

Comment: Yes, as I said, same format, same size, same attributes. Have a look at the file with PDFDebugger.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for the second part of the question (tested by myself):

```
InputStream is = img2.getStream().getCOSObject().createRawInputStream();
OutputStream os = img1.getStream().getCOSObject().createRawOutputStream();

IOUtils.copy(is, os);
is.close();
os.close();

img1.getStream().getCOSObject().clear();
img1.getStream().getCOSObject().addAll(img2.getStream().getCOSObject().asUnmodifiableDictionary());
```